# Unsupported csproj file

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2017, .net-4.5

I have a requirement to migrate from .net framework 4.0 to 4.5.2. When I am trying to open a framework 4.0 solution in visual studio 2017. I am getting below error for one of the projects

Complete error:

This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects. The project types may not be installed or this version of Visual Studio may not support them. 
For more information on enabling these project types or otherwise migrating your assets, please see the details in the "Migration Report" displayed after clicking OK.

The migration report is taking me to:
The application which this project type is based on was not found. Please try this link for further information: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=299083&projecttype=F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325

Below are my ProjectTypeGuids:

{F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}

All except mvc5.0 is installed on my machine which is a nuget package.

Is it possible to have mvc 5 in .net 4.0 framework application?

Could you suggest what i am missing?

Comment: Is it a reporting project?

Comment: nope. A C#, MVC2 web application

Comment: Right, what is the exact version of Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: visual studio 15.5.4

Comment: hmm ok, ASP.NET 5 goes with .NET 4.5 and above. Can you try changing the target framework version

Comment: i got to change the target framework as that is the requirement to migrate to 4.5.2. but that dosnt solve the problem. Another thing is when the original framework is 4.0 how come mvc 5 guid?

Comment: Nothing very special about that project, it is an asp.net mvc 5 project written in C#.  VS2017 has a fancy installer that lets you pick what kind of projects you want to work on.  Run it again to ensure you selected asp.net support.

Comment: C#/MVC 2 web app needs a migration wizard to be opened, which is probably not yet installed. As others indicated, you can review VS2017 installation, or perform upgrade in an older VS release.